# Please tell my error in this knapsack 0/1 problem

Tags: arrays, dynamic, knapsack-problem

input
first line:[input is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnNKa.png)

here n is no. of element , W is max possible weight we can take.
wi and vi are weights of individual element and their corresponding value.

my code is as follows but it gives out some unknown output.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int knap(int* dp,int *we,int *v,int n,int w,int lev){
    if(lev<0)
    return 0;
if(dp[w]!=-1)
    return dp[w];
int c1,c2,temp;
if(w>=we[lev])
c1=knap(dp,we,v,n,w-we[lev],lev-1)+v[lev];
c2=knap(dp,we,v,n,w,lev-1);
return dp[w]=max(c1,c2);
}
int main(){
int n,w;
cin>>n>>w;
int we[n];
int v[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>we[i]>>v[i];
int dp[w+1];
for(int i=0;i<=w;i++)
    dp[i]=-1;
dp[0]=0;
cout<<knap(dp,we,v,n,w,n-1);
}
```

[test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71H6C.png)

[test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP6Ca.png)
pls point out the mistake.